# Do male Aes Sedai become ageless?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

One of the most noticeable features of female Aes Sedai is the ageless appearance of their face. They don't start out that way, but it develops the longer they've been using the Power.

But do male Aes Sedai face this same effect (see what I did there)? Are there any mentions of it? I recall Asmodean looking like a middle-aged man, but that would imply he actually does appear a specific age - not to mention that the Forsaken seem capable of changing their looks.

Is it possible we don't know, since men who can channel rarely live long?

Comment: How far into the books are you?

Comment: I agree, we really need to know how far you are.  I believe there may be evidence; but based on some of the info in the question, it might be spoilers.

Comment: Thanks for checking! I hate spoilers. I'm just a few chapters into Book 5, _The Fires of Heaven_.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, male Aes Sedai do not *normally* gain the ageless appearance to their face.

More of an explanation will require spoilers, so do **not** hover over the following unless you are willing to have some (relatively minor) plot points spoiled for you!

> Men do not get the "ageless look" because they do not swear oaths on the Oath Rod.  The Oath Rod (or, arguably, the oaths sworn on the ter'angreal) is what causes that particular ageless look.  Notable evidence is that the Kin, the Forsaken, the Wise Ones and the damane do not have ageless faces, despite centuries worth of channeling. Egwene herself states to Romanda in *Crossroads of Twilight*, Chapter 30 that the Oath Rod is the cause of agelessness.  This is confirmed in an [interview](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Source:Budapest_Q%26A,_April_2003) by Robert Jordan himself.

Comment: To be fair, the initial premise of the question is even somewhat flawed.  Only _modern_ Aes Sedai become ageless; due to the spoiler-y reasons you've mentioned.  It's also funny how the ageless _look_ actually effects age.

Comment: As a point blaming (spoiler) is silly.  it's just a random jump to a conclusion made by a character.  It could be anything else

Comment: @Andrey It's just a random conclusion... except for the strong circumstantial evidence I mentioned... and the [Word of God confirmation](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Source:Budapest_Q%26A,_April_2003) (**again, this link contains major spoilers!**)